# OAuthRequestValidator Access Token and Access Token Secret

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I am trying to add an account to QuickBooks Online using Intuit IPP:

https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0200_DevKits_for_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0100_IPP_.NET_DevKit/Query_Filters/QuickBooks_Online

How do I get the access token and the access token secret? Here is my code:

```
class Program
{
    static string appToken = "xxx";
    static string oAuthConsumerKey = "xxx";
    static string oAuthConsumerSecret = "xxx";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        OAuthRequestValidator oauthValidator = new OAuthRequestValidator(appToken, "", oAuthConsumerKey, oAuthConsumerSecret);
        ServiceContext context = new ServiceContext(oauthValidator, appToken, "1234", IntuitServicesType.QBD);
        DataServices dataServices = new DataServices(context);


        Account account = new Account();
        account.Desc = "TEST PLEASE DELETE";
        string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
        guid = guid.Substring(0, 30);
        account.Name = guid;
        account.Type = Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.AccountTypeEnum.Liability;
        account.TypeSpecified = true;
        account.Subtype = "Accounts Payable";
        Account resultAccount = dataServices.Add(account) as Account;

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am having the same issue

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. Look at step 6 here:

http://ippblog.intuit.com/blog/2012/09/ode-to-oauth-and-rest-apis-and-how-i-love-thee-not.html

Answer (score 2):

Joseph,
For Future reference and for others the documentation for your question is located here:

[IPP Oauth Documentation](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0020_Connect/0010_From_Within_Your_App/Implement_OAuth_in_Your_App)

regards,
Jarred